# PHP Create datetime variable from a string variable

Tags: php

I want to create a new datetime variable from a string variable using `datetime` function.
So, I have:
`$sqlData=$day . "." . $month . "." . $year;`
`echo $sqlData;`

`$local=new datetime('${sqlData}');`
`echo $local;`

The problem appear on `echo $local;`

Error msg: `Failed to parse time string (${sqlData}), unexpected character'`

Comment: `'${sqlData}'` should be `"${sqlData}"`

Comment: @Nick Is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you think you need the `{` and `'` in DateTime?
`$sqlData` is a string, and DateTime wants a string. So why not just give it the string?

```
$sqlData=$day . "." . $month . "." . $year;
echo $sqlData;

$local=new datetime($sqlData);
var_dump($local);
```

Then echo won't work since it's an object, so var_dump/print_r or var_export

https://3v4l.org/nq8iY

To echo the string you need to format the object.

```
echo $local->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Is not working, `Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string`

Comment: Did you just try to echo the object even though I explicitly wrote you can't echo an object? What exactly are you expecting? The date? The object itself?

Comment: yes, sorry for that but I need to echo this variable

Comment: As a string? Then why bother with DateTime at all. Just place your day, month and year variables as you like and echo them. I don't understand why you create a DateTime object you don't use

Comment: I'll need to use later as an object

Comment: https://3v4l.org/f8mNH you need to format the object.

Comment: Ofcourse I format that object but the problem was solved after I removed `Var_dump($local);` . Thank you

Comment: I don't see how a commented line can ever be a problem, but ok.

Comment: Not the commented line....

Answer (score 2):

This below worked for me, you need to set the format and return it as a new variable.

```
   <?php
    $date = 05; $month = 05; $year = 1990;
    $sqlData="$date.$month.$year";
    $local=new datetime($sqlData);
    $date = $local->format('Y/m/d');
    echo $date;
```